# Calculate duration of time under threshold in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-manipulation, summary

I have a dataset with ID, time, value. I want to calculate the total time for the my value stays below 1 in the dataset for each subject.

```
 library(data.table)     
ID<-rep(1:10,each=10)
    time<-rep(1:10,times=10)
    value<-rep(c(0.001,0.01,0.05,0.07,0.09,0.096,0.1,0.5,1,2),10)
    df<-cbind(ID,time,value)
    df<-as.data.frame(df)
    # # 
    df_sum<-setDT(df)[value < 1, diff(range(time)), by = .(ID)]
```

In this dataset set the expected answer is 8 hours. I am getting 7 hours.
Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `value < 1`, you are removing one key row.

```r
df[ID == 1, ]
#        ID  time value     v    t2
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:     1     1 0.001 0.001     0
#  2:     1     2 0.010 0.011     1
#  3:     1     3 0.050 0.061     2
#  4:     1     4 0.070 0.131     3
#  5:     1     5 0.090 0.221     4
#  6:     1     6 0.096 0.317     5
#  7:     1     7 0.100 0.417     6
#  8:     1     8 0.500 0.917     7
#  9:     1     9 1.000 1.917     8
# 10:     1    10 2.000 3.917     9
df[ID == 1, ][value < 1, ]
#       ID  time value     v    t2
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1     1 0.001 0.001     0
# 2:     1     2 0.010 0.011     1
# 3:     1     3 0.050 0.061     2
# 4:     1     4 0.070 0.131     3
# 5:     1     5 0.090 0.221     4
# 6:     1     6 0.096 0.317     5
# 7:     1     7 0.100 0.417     6
# 8:     1     8 0.500 0.917     7
```

For which the range of `time` spaces from `0` to `7`, which is indeed `7`.

I think you need one of two solutions:

1. `diff(range(.))+1`, since you want to know `7-0+1=8`:

   ```r
   df[ value < 1, diff(range(time)) + 1, by = ID]
   #        ID    V1
   #     <num> <num>
   #  1:     1     8
   #  2:     2     8
   #  3:     3     8
   #  4:     4     8
   #  5:     5     8
   #  6:     6     8
   #  7:     7     8
   #  8:     8     8
   #  9:     9     8
   # 10:    10     8
   ```
2. Include `value` of 1:

   ```r
   df[ value <= 1, diff(range(time)), by = ID]
   ```

Comment: Thank you. How can I calculate the proportion of patients at each time point for which value is below 1. In this case 100% ID have value below "1" from 1-8 hours.

Comment: `df[, sum(value < 1)/.N, by = time]`

Comment: Thank you r2evans! This is very helpful. I am unable to up vote the answer.

Comment: I understand, but I suggested *accepting* it (and previous questions), not upvoting it. Look under the up/down vote arrows, you should be able to click on a checkmark.

Comment: (And now you should be able to upvote as well.)